# Upgrade from 10.04 to 14.04 ubuntu desktop

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 10.04

I am running 10.04 ubuntu version and since it's out dated now, I want to switch to 14.04. Can I upgrade to 14.04 from 10.04 or do I have to re-install the distribution. Also my ubuntu 10.04 is a 32 bit OS and hence I want 14.04 to be 64-bit.

Some specifications of my current system are:

```
lscpu
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
CPU(s):                2
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
CPU socket(s):         1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 23
Stepping:              10
CPU MHz:               2992.621
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              6144K
```

Also running this gives

```
getconf LONG_BIT
32
```

and

```
uname -a

Linux Sal 2.6.32-73-generic-pae #141-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 10 17:30:23 UTC 2015 **i686** GNU/Linux
```

I know my machine can support 64 -bit OS.

So how can I upgrade it??

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Comment: Also: http://askubuntu.com/q/115835/158442, http://askubuntu.com/q/5018/158442

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: Irrespective of the fact that you would have to go the 10.04 --> 12.04 --> 14.04 way, as all the previous answers to the same question indicate, you can not change architecture when upgrading. Go the fresh install way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I switch a 32-bit installation to a 64-bit one?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81824/how-can-i-switch-a-32-bit-installation-to-a-64-bit-one)